# Laravel: Trying to get url (with prefix) in complete laravel application

Tags: laravel-5

Using Laravel 5.6 version. I have following code in routes/web.php file

```
Route::prefix('farmapp')->group(function () {

Route::get('/', 'Admin\DashboardController@index');

Route::get('/units', 'Admin\UnitController@index');

});
```

As you can see above, I am using prefix `'farmapp'` so that all application url's start with `'farmapp'`, e.g `localhost/arainfarms/farmapp` and `localhost/arainfarms/farmapp/units`

Now coming to menubar/sidebar links:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs border-0 flex-column flex-lg-row">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a href="{{ url('farmapp/') }}" class="nav-link active"><i class="fe fe-home"></i> Home</a>
   </li>

  <li class="nav-item">
    <a href="{{ url('farmapp/units') }}" class="nav-link"><i class="fe fe-check-square"></i> Farm Units</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

As you can see I am using `farmapp` prefix  in every `url`.
In future if I want to change `farmapp` to some other prefix, I can easily change in web file, but as there are so many links in sidebar and other application files and I have to change `farmapp` to new one in all these files and it's some time taking process..so is there any way/strategy/Laravel Function to update all these url's automatically by changing prefix in web file? In short I don't want to add prefix in all these file url's. By giving prefix on web , this prefix must automatically add in sidebar/other files.

Comment: You could get around this by using named routes and refercing them via {{ route('yourname') }} in your blade files.

Comment: Ok will try that

Comment: @mynd well in that case we have to make changes in blade files..

Comment: Yes, you have to change the blade files once but from then on you are pretty much independent from how they are named since you are referencing them by a given name independent from the actual url structure. Since you have to change your blade files anyway (because of the currently used, hard-coded /farmapp prefix) this will make the approach at least future proof.

Comment: OK..I got your point..It almost solves my problem..thank you

Comment: Ok, nice, good luck